# Python integral calculator doesn't print a value

Tags: python, integration, taylor-series

I have made a calculator that approximates any given function as an input. They later I want it to calculate an integral, but after writing:

```
function    = str(input("The function that must be expanded and integrated: "))
```

It doesn't print a number but instead a value. This is my code:

```
from sympy.functions import sin,cos,tan
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import *
from sympy import series
from math import *
function    = str(input("The function that must be expanded and integrated: "))
x0          = int(input("Point of development: "))
n           = int(input("Amount of expressions: "))

print(series(function, x, x0, n))

N = int(input("Amount of summs (Bigger number is more accurate but takes longer time): "))
a = int(input("Integrate from: "))
b = int(input("Integrate to: "))

# We will use the midpoint method to integrate the function

def integrate(N, a, b):
    def f(x):
        return series(function, x, x0, n)
    value=0
    value=2
    for n in range(1, N+1):
        value += f(a+((n-(1/2))*((b-a)/N)))
    value2 = ((b-a)/N)*value
    return value2

print("...................")
print("Here is your answer: ")
print(integrate(N, a, b))
```

I think, it's because my input is a string. However I can't choose my input to be an integer, because `exp(-x**2)` isn't an integer. If that's the case, how can I input any function in my calculater and still get a value?

Comment: You need to map the string to a function to execute. In case you want to input `'exp(-x**2)'` as string, you would also need to parse it intos stuffs to do

Comment: Might be a dupe of [Evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Comment: why do you set `value=0` and on the very next line `value=2`? why are `N`, `a` and `b` parameters of `integrate`, but not `function`, `x0` and `n`. I would prefer wither using all as parameters, or none of them.

Comment: why do you use both Taylor polynomial approximation and midpoint approximation? Wouldn't it be better *either* use midpoint rule directly to the original function *or* integrate precisely/analytically the Taylor polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a some significant issues in your code:

- inside `integrate`, you are using local variable `n`, but inside `f(x)` you consider it to be the global `n` (but the local is used, which is what you want, just print `n` inside the `f(x)`). The same holds for `x` as a global variable and parameter in `f(x)`. Do not use same names for global and local variables if you want to use both in the same scope.
- the return value of `f(x)` is a `sympy` epxression, not a single value, that's why you get the output what you get.

After some refactoring and using [`subs`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution) and [`removeO`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.expr.Expr.removeO):

```py
from sympy.functions import sin,cos,tan
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import series

function    = str(input("The function to be expanded and integrated: "))
x0          = int(input("Point of development: "))
n           = 1 + int(input("Degree: "))
# input 0 -> n=1 -> constant  (1 term, constant)
# input 1 -> n=2 -> linear    (2 terms, constant + linear)
# input 2 -> n=3 -> quadratic (3 terms, constant + linear + quadratic)
# ...

print(series(function, x, x0, n))

N = int(input("Amount of summs (Bigger number is more accurate but takes longer time): "))
a = int(input("Integrate from: "))
b = int(input("Integrate to: "))

# We will use the midpoint method to integrate the function

def integrate(function, x0, n, N, a, b): # using the approach with all variables as parameters
    taylor = series(function, x, x0, n) # the same expression for the function, create it once
    taylor = taylor.removeO() # do not use O term (may corrups subs below)
    dx = (b-a)/N # also computed just once
    def f(v):
        return taylor.subs(x,v) # taylor is expression, return value is float evaluated with substituted x by v
    return dx * sum(f(a+(i+1/2)*dx) for i in range(N)) # simple sum function, can be rewriten using a for loop

print("...................")
print("Here is your answer: ")
print(integrate(function, x0, n, N, a, b))
```

Some outputs for `x**2` integrated from `x=0` to `x=2` expanded at `x=1`. Analytical result is `8/3=2.6666666...`.

```
x**2, 1, 0, 5, 0, 2 => 2.0 # constant approximation
x**2, 1, 1, 5, 0, 2 => 2.0 # linear approximation
x**2, 1, 2, 5, 0, 2 => 2.64 # quadratic approximation - exact function
x**2, 1, 2, 10, 0, 2 => 2.66
x**2, 1, 2, 100, 0, 2 => 2.6666
x**2, 1, 2, 1000, 0, 2 => 2.666666
```

You can use [`lambdify` to "convert a SymPy expression into a function that allows for fast numeric evaluation"](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify). For the case of `N=1000` the speedup is significant.

```py
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
def integrate(function, x0, n, N, a, b):
    taylor = series(function, x, x0, n)
    taylor = lambdify(x,taylor.removeO()) # here
    dx = (b-a)/N
    def f(v):
        return taylor(v) # here
    return dx * sum(f(a+(i+1/2)*dx) for i in range(N))
```

Comment: Thank you, the only thing is, let's say I plot in `exp(-x**2)` as the function, it is waaay off, why is that?

Comment: Please provide the other parameters. As I asked below OP, you do **two** approximations, each one producing some error. Either use Taylor polynomial approximation or the midpoint rule, you should get better results

Comment: Yeah i figured it out. When approximating the function with 1000 degrees and 1000 sums it's much more accurate. I will attempt to implement lambdify to speed up the calculation. Thank you!

Comment: I am still curious why you use **both** Taylor polynomials **and** midpoint rule. Start choosing **either** precise evaluation of the Taylor polynomial **or** using midpoint rule on *the original function*. From 1000x1000 problem you come to 1000000x1 problem, much better results with the same resources

Comment: I am doing that simply because it's for a school project, in which both methods must be represented. If that wasn't the case, I completely agree with you, either using Taylor expansion or the midpoint rule on its own would be much more favorable.